# C# lambda in interface implementation

Tags: c#, lambda, interface

I have read some about lambda.
But I have problems with the code below, Who can explain to me?

```
public class FakeProductRepository : IProductRepository 
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products => new List<Product> 
    {
        new Product { Name = "Football", Price = 25 },
        new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price = 179 },
        new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price = 95 }
    };
}
```

how `public IEnumerable<Product> Products => new List<Product>` work??
Why when I use "=" instead of "=>" error occurs?:

> Error CS0535  'FakeProductRepository' does not implement interface
>   member 'IProductRepository.Products'

Comment: This is an expression-bodied function member, see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodied-function-members

Comment: The difference is that using `=>` means `Products` is a property.  Using `=` means it's a field.  Note however that is the equivalent of `public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get { return new List<Product>{...};}}` so it's going to create the list every time the property getter is called.

Comment: (maybe not the best dupe target, happy to unhammer if someone finds a better one!)

Comment: @DavidG looks like a good dupe target to me.